# Angular Charts - not able to read data

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, chart.js

First time using `chart.js` and I have an issue of the chart not being able to read the data from the model.

Earlier I had an error of `Error: $injector:modulerr Module Failed to instantiate module chart.js`. This was resolved by changing the dependency from `chart.js`, to `angularCharts`, though majority (near enough all) use `chart.js`. I have written the required controllers and poperties/values but the the graph won't read the data.

Not sure what the issue is, whether it be I am using the wrong dependency (`angularCharts`) or issue with the `$scope`. Any ideas?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-charts/0.2.7/angular-charts.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-6 text-xs-center" ng-controller="LineCtrl">
    <h2>Cost Analysis</h2>
    <canvas class="chart chart-line" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" 
    chart-series="series" chart-click="onClick"></canvas> 
</div>
```

---

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'angularMoment', 'ui.router', 'angularCharts']);

app.controller("LineCtrl", ['$scope', '$timeout', function ($scope, $timeout) {

  $scope.labels = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"];
  $scope.series = ['Series A', 'Series B'];
  $scope.data = [
    [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
    [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
  ];
  $scope.onClick = function (points, evt) {
    console.log(points, evt);
  };

  // Simulate async data update
  $timeout(function () {
    $scope.data = [
      [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90],
      [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
    ];
  }, 3000);

}])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing the wrong library.

You have imported `angular-charts` located at https://github.com/chinmaymk/angular-charts.

But, you are using directives that are a part of `angular-chart` located at http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/

You were correct at first when you were including the `chart.js` dependency, you just have the wrong library.

```
angular.module('myModule', ['chart.js']);
```

Here is a working version of your code: https://plnkr.co/edit/tUsMwgOBcFJrV1xTMcF0?p=preview

Comment: I literally a couple of minutes ago worked that out. I swear the amount of time I lose to stupid errors. Thank you